# Partitioning a USB Drive

Tags: linux, windows, boot, usb, partitioning

I've read other answers; none of which answer my question for different limitations.

**Goal:** Partition a USB to 3 sections: Data (FAT32) , Kon Boot (Bootable with EFI), Linux Live CD (Bootable with EFI). Of course, the USB needs to be able to accomplish all of these (if it can be booted from) on any PC, irrespective of the PC boot configuration.

**Problems:**

- Windows can only see the first partition (SOLVED by arrangement).
- Can't get Linux to boot; Kon Boot immediately takes over (SOLVED by rEFInd).
- Can't install Live Linux CD. See "**EDIT**"

---

**Proposed Solution:**

To use Data partition as the first one (Will automatically appear/mount in Windows).

Then use rEFInd in the second partition, and configure it to boot either the third (Kon Boot) partition or the fourth (Linux Live CD).

So will this work? And how do I go about doing it (as in commands :P)?

**EDIT**

I can confirm it all works, except installing Live Linux CD on the last part. The problem is that Linux CDs are installed like `dd if=Linux.iso of=/dev/sdX` when I actually need it to be `sdXY` where `Y` may be a specific partition of the USB. If I use `sdXY` it just breaks and doesn't boot.

Comment: I've wondered about doing this myself. But usb drives are dirt cheap. I can't imagine it's worth your time to figure this out than to just buy 2 more usb drives.

Comment: This isn't about the economical problem, it's about the practical problem this solves.

Comment: Truth is breaking live iso to make the content boot on a partition is always a mess. Even loop booting the iso file with grub instead can be easier: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive ; btw you may not even need to partition the drive at all since your data partition is FAT32 so it can be the ESP too

Comment: This would have been interesting except: "For UEFI [GRUB], the partition has to be the first one in an MBR partition table and formatted with FAT32". This brings me back to problem 1. Though I may revert to this and sacrifice Data partition if my current endeavor fails.

Comment: Try adding the rEFInd ISO-9660 driver. Once this is in place, rEFInd should detect your CD image on `/dev/sdXY`.

Comment: I've just written an answer. All is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It worked!**

Here's how I went about doing this after some reading into how everything works, and man, rEFInd is just awesomely adaptive to whatever you throw at it.

- To solve the first problem, just partition the USB to have FAT32 Data partition first.
- To solve the second problem where some bootables are not detected, use the awesome tool called [rEFInd](http://rodsbooks.com/refind/) (download the CD-R package). It will detect all `.efi` loaders.
- Install Kon Boot in its partition.
- Now this was the tricky part (for me, at least). Making a bootable Linux CD without installing a dedicated ESP partition. After a whole lot of trial and error, even with different bootloaders, I simply mounted the image and extracted the `EFI` folder as-is. Then I accessed the ISO file as an archive and extracted all content. Finally I went to my desired USB partition and pasted the extracted ISO content and then also pasted the EFI folder, both in the root of the partition.

Now rEFInd can allow me to boot any system at will.

**Further exploration:** Simplifying the structure of the USB.

Seeing how forgiving rEFInd is, I'll try just mixing everything bootable in one single partition, each system in a folder instead of a partition, while still keeping the first Data partition visible for Windows. Further simplification into ONE single FAT32 partition isn't so far fetched from what I found trying stuff out... I think it can work for storage AND booting.

**Final setup**:

- Create 3 partitions: FAT32 (in GB for Data), FAT32 (150MB for ESPUSB), EXT4 (Linux Live)
- Create this structure in ESPUSB: [EFI], [VARIABLE], [VARIABLE]

[EFI] is a folder called `EFI`

[VARIABLE] depends on if the MOUNTED Linux ISO has any other folders next to its `EFI` folder. Just duplicate the MOUNTED ISO structure in ESPUSB

- Install rEFInd, as documented, in ESPUSB (EFI/boot/*.efi structure)
- Extract KonBoot zip and rename "boot" to "KonBoot". Then take "KonBoot" and "USBFILES" folders and paste them in ESPUSB/EFI/[HERE]
- From the MOUNTED Linux ISO, enter EFI folder, and rename "Boot" to "LinuxBoot". Then take the "LinuxBoot" folder and paste it in ESPUSB/EFI/[HERE]

Final ESPUSB structure will be:

EFI +- VARIABLES

EFI > Boot (for rEFInd) + KonBoot + LinuxBoot

^ Inside each of them will have *.efi files to boot the specific option.

- Then to create bootable Linux Live CD, just EXTRACT all Linux.iso content and paste it in the EXT4 partition (Optional: also make vmlinuz.img and initrd.img links in the root of the EXT4).

This may work for others, so I kept it here. It will also serve as my notes for the future; let me know if you're shutting Superuser down anytime soon, mods.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [special USB flash drive](http://www.ironkey.com/en-US/windows-to-go-drives/ironkey-workspace-w300.html) which identifies to the system as fixed disk and not as removable. Otherwise Windows only sees 1 partition.

Comment: The Windows problem is easily solved using the first part of the solution. Just put the Data section first. The other two (three?) partitions have no need to be visible in Windows.